# UITableView inside UIPickerView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am struck at a problem where I need to implement a multiple type selection picker so for this purpose i am doing this :

```
caratFromPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    caratTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:caratFromPicker.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    caratTable.delegate = self;
    caratTable.dataSource = self;
    caratTable.bounces = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-caratFromPicker.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil];
    [toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
    price1.inputView = caratFromPicker;
    price1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
    [caratFromPicker setDataSource: self];
    [caratFromPicker setDelegate: self];
    caratFromPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;//loadFromPicker
    [caratFromPicker addSubview:caratTable];
```

and implemented the UITableView delegates as :

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return [caratFromArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    cell.textLabel.text = [caratFromArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

here is the screenshot of the same :
[image]

but my problem is I am not able to scroll the tableview to view next values.

Comment: before the answer to the question what you get is a edit from someone :) :) :)

Comment: hahahhahaha..... Awesome agent chocks....!!! thats true

Comment: Why are you putting a table view inside a picker view? This seems highly unusual. Can you provide some screenshots of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you adding the UITableView? Are you sure your UITableView is within the bounds?

Comment: yes tableview is within the bounds of picker

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @iRiziya unfortunately no... can you help (currently i used another control)

Comment: @AgentChocks. I made a custom uipickerview with multiselection. Will share the code soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UIPicker delegate method :

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)theView{
    return YourTableView;
}
```

To set tableView as the view for the row.